# How to use antd styling in v5.x.x?

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd

Previously, we were using antd v4.x.x and have now upgraded to the latest antd version v5.x.x

We were using below 2 .less files with antd v4.x.x

`antd/lib/style/themes/default.less`

`antd/dist/antd.less`

But now we have upgraded to antd v5.x.x which does not support .less files anymore.

However, we have upgraded our override.less file to override.css, but how can we get default styling which we get from default.less & antd.less in v5.x.x ?

Comment: Do [this](https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#less-migration) helps you?

Comment: We have shifted to CSS from less, but how to use default.less & antd.less which we get in antd v4.x.x ?